# C generic typesafe dynamic array (vector) try 2

Tags: c, array, vectors

The previous [generic dynamic array I asked a review for](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277874/c-generic-dynamic-array-using-preprocessor/) here was written using only the preprocessor and so while the array itself was type-safe, all the manipulating macros where not.

In this try I wrote a dynamic array that stores the element size, and then a macro interface that hides it as an implementation detail.
I also took advice from the previous review and removed the `arrayMap(array,callback)` macro and replaced it with `VEC_FOREACH(index_variable_name, vec)` which is simply a wrapper around a `for` loop.

**A note on memory allocation:** as I'm still testing this array, I didn't add any code to gracefully handle memory allocation errors yet.

The code is currently in a single file, and isn't ready yet to be included by other files yet.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h> // offsetof
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct vec_header {
    uint32_t used;
    uint32_t capacity;
    uint32_t element_size;
    char data[];
} VecHeader;

union align {
    int i;
    long l;
    long *lp;
    void *p;
    void (*fp)(void);
    float f;
    double d;
    long double ld;
};

union header {
    VecHeader h;
    union align a;
};

VecHeader *_vec_make_header(uint32_t element_size, uint32_t capacity) {
    VecHeader *h = calloc(1, element_size * capacity + sizeof(union header));
    assert(h);
    h->capacity = capacity;
    h->element_size = element_size;
    return h;
}


static inline VecHeader *_vec_to_header(void *vec) {
    assert(vec);
    return vec - offsetof(VecHeader, data);
}

void _vec_free_header(VecHeader *h) {
    free(h);
}

void _vec_ensure_capacity(void **vec, uint32_t capacity) {
    assert(vec && *vec);
    VecHeader *h = _vec_to_header(*vec);
    if(h->used >= capacity) {
        return;
    }
    h->capacity = capacity;
    h = realloc(h, h->element_size * h->capacity +sizeof(union header));
    assert(h);
    *vec = (void *)h->data;
}

void *_vec_prepare_push(void **vec) {
    assert(vec && *vec);
    VecHeader *h = _vec_to_header(*vec);
    if(h->used + 1 > h->capacity) {
        h->capacity *= 2;
        h = realloc(h, h->element_size * h->capacity + sizeof(union header));
        assert(h);
    }
    h->used++;
    *vec = (void *)h->data;
    return h->data + (h->used - 1) * h->element_size;
}


void *_vec_pop(VecHeader *h) {
    assert(h && h->used > 0);
    h->used--;
    return h->data + h->used * h->element_size;
}

void *_vec_get(VecHeader *h, uint32_t index) {
    assert(h && index < h->used);
    return h->data + index * h->element_size;
}

void _vec_copy(void **dest_vec, VecHeader *src) {
    assert(dest_vec && *dest_vec && src);
    VecHeader *dest = _vec_to_header(*dest_vec);
    assert(dest->element_size == src->element_size);
    dest->used = 0; // clear the destination vec.
    _vec_ensure_capacity(dest_vec, src->capacity);
    dest = _vec_to_header(*dest_vec); // needed in case of reallocation in above call.
    // both loops can be replaced with 'memcpy(dest->data, src->data, i * src->element_size);
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < src->used; ++i) {
        for(uint32_t j = 0; j < src->element_size; ++j) {
            dest->data[i * dest->element_size + j] = src->data[i * src->element_size + j];
        }
    }
    _vec_to_header(*dest_vec)->used = src->used;
}

void _vec_reverse(void *vec) {
    assert(vec);
    VecHeader *h = _vec_to_header(vec);
    // The division below might result in a float in which
    // case it will be rounded down which is what we want.
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < h->used / 2; ++i) {
        for(uint32_t j = 0; j < h->element_size; ++j) {
            char tmp = h->data[i * h->element_size + j];
            h->data[i * h->element_size + j] = h->data[(h->used - i - 1) * h->element_size + j];
            h->data[(h->used - i - 1) * h->element_size + j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

#define VEC_INITIAL_SIZE 8

#define VEC_NEW(type) ((type *)(_vec_make_header(sizeof(type), VEC_INITIAL_SIZE)->data))
#define VEC_FREE(vec) (_vec_free_header(_vec_to_header((void *)vec)))

#define VEC_CAPACITY(vec) (_vec_to_header((void *)vec)->capacity)
#define VEC_LENGTH(vec) (_vec_to_header((void *)vec)->used)

#define VEC_PUSH(vec, value) (*(typeof(vec))(_vec_prepare_push((void **)&(vec))) = (value))
#define VEC_POP(vec) (*(typeof(vec))_vec_pop(_vec_to_header((void *)vec)))
#define VEC_GET(vec, index) (*(typeof(vec))_vec_get(_vec_to_header((void *)vec), index))

#define VEC_COPY(dest, src) (_vec_copy((void **)&(dest), _vec_to_header((void *)src)))
#define VEC_CLEAR(vec) ((void)(_vec_to_header((void *)vec)->used = 0))

#define VEC_REVERSE(vec) (_vec_reverse((void *)(vec)))

#define VEC_FOREACH(index_var_name, vec) for(uint32_t index_var_name = 0; index_var_name < VEC_LENGTH(vec); ++index_var_name)
// Note: [vec] is referenced multiple times.
#define VEC_ITERATE(iter_var_name, vec) for(typeof(*vec) *iter_var_name = (vec); iter_var_name - (vec) < VEC_LENGTH(vec); ++iter_var_name)
```

An example usage:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int *nums = VEC_NEW(int);
    VEC_PUSH(nums, 42);
    VEC_PUSH(nums, 123);

    VEC_FOREACH(i, nums) {
        printf("nums[%u] = %d\n", i, nums[i]); // VEC_GET(nums, i) checks bounds.
    }

    int *nums2 = VEC_NEW(int);
    VEC_COPY(nums2, nums);
    printf("len: %u, cap: %u, nums2[len] = %d\n", VEC_LENGTH(nums2), VEC_CAPACITY(nums2), VEC_POP(nums2));
    VEC_CLEAR(nums2);
    VEC_FREE(nums2);
    VEC_FREE(nums);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really like the [DbC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) precondition checks, such as `assert(h && h->used > 0);`. Consider writing **multiple** asserts, one per conjunct. It is "equivalent", yes. But in the unlikely event that, say, 2nd conjunct fails, then the line number of the assert diagnostic will give us valuable debugging information that the combined expression will not. No biggie, just something to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should `vec_header.data` be a `uint8_t` instead of a char?

`VEC_NEW` asserts and fails on an allocation error.  It could return NULL and let the caller decide how to handle out-of-memory errors.

Why does `_vec_ensure_capacity` test that `h->used` is greater than the desired capacity, rather than `h->capacity`?  This means you may reallocate when the destination is large enough, but not full. And when `used` is bigger than the new capacity, you don't reallocate - leaving around the old values with no way to access them.

`_vec_prepare_push` could call  `_vec_ensure_capacity` to avoid having two very similar blocks of code that call  `realloc`.

The last line of `_vec_copy` shouldn't need another call to `_vec_to_header`: `dest` already has that value.

Technically, the division in `_vec_reverse` won't result in a float, but it will be rounded toward zero as you state.

In `_vec_reverse`, I might use two local variables for the repeated index calculations:  `uint32_t front = i * h->element_size + j; rear = (h->used - i - 1) * h->element_size + j;`